# Chrome extension: how to pass ArrayBuffer or Blob from content script to the background without losing its type?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, typed-arrays, xmlhttprequest-level2

I have this content script that downloads some binary data using XHR, which is sent later to the background script:

```
var self = this;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
     self.data = {
        data: xhr.response,
        contentType: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
     };
  }
};
xhr.send();

... later ...
sendResponse({data: self.data});
```

After receiving this data in background script, I'd like to form another XHR request that uploads this binary data to my server, so I do:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder();
bb.append(data.data);
formData.append("data", bb.getBlob(data.contentType));
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", serverUrl);
req.send(formData);
```

The problem is that the file uploaded to the server contains just this string: "[object Object]". I guess this happens because ArrayBuffer type is lost somehow while transferring it from content process to the background? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Messages passed between a Content Script and a background page are JSON-serialized.

If you want to transfer an `ArrayBuffer` object through a JSON-serialized channel, wrap the buffer in a view, before and after transferring.

I show an isolated example, so that the solution is generally applicable, and not just in your case. The example shows how to pass around `ArrayBuffer`s and typed arrays, but the method can also be applied to `File` and `Blob` objects, by using the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API.

```
// In your case: self.data = { data: new Uint8Array(xhr.response), ...
// Generic example:
var example = new ArrayBuffer(10);
var data = {
    // Create a view
    data: Array.apply(null, new Uint8Array(example)),
    contentType: 'x-an-example'
};

// Transport over a JSON-serialized channel. In your case: sendResponse
var transportData = JSON.stringify(data);
//"{"data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"contentType":"x-an-example"}"

// At the receivers end. In your case: chrome.extension.onRequest
var receivedData = JSON.parse(transportData);

// data.data is an Object, NOT an ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array
receivedData.data = new Uint8Array(receivedData.data).buffer;
// Now, receivedData is the expected ArrayBuffer object
```

This solution has been tested successfully in Chrome 18 and Firefox.

- **[`new Uint8Array(xhr.response)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array)** is used to create a view of the [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer), so that the individual bytes can be read.
- **`Array.apply(null, <Uint8Array>)`** is used to create a plain array, using the keys from the `Uint8Array` view. This step reduces the size of the serialized message. **WARNING: This method only works for small amounts of data. When the size of the typed array exceeds 125836, a RangeError will be thrown. If you need to handle large pieces of data, use other methods to do the conversion between typed arrays and plain arrays.**
- At the receivers end, the original buffer can be obtained by [creating a new `Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array#Constructor), and reading the [`buffer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView#Attributes).

### Implementation in your Google Chrome extension:

```
// Part of the Content script
    self.data = {
        data: Array.apply(null, new Uint8Array(xhr.response)),
        contentType: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
    };
...
sendResponse({data: self.data});

// Part of the background page
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(data, sender, callback) {
    ...
    data.data = new Uint8Array(data.data).buffer;
```

### Documentation

- MDN: [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays)
- MDN: [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer)
- MDN: [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array)
- MDN: [`<Function> .apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- Google Chrome Extension docs: [Messaging > Simple one-time requests](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#simple)
  *"This lets you send a one-time **JSON-serializable message** from a content script to extension, or vice versa, respectively"*
- SO bonus: [Upload a File in a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002486/938089?upload-a-file-in-a-google-chrome-extension) - Using a Web worker to request, validate, process and submit binary data.

Comment: This `Array.apply(null, new Uint8Array(xhr.response))` doesn't work for big buffers (bigger than 150Kb) raising `Maximum call stack size exceeded`error. Even for small buffers probably it is better to pass binary strings that JS arrays.

Comment: For bigger arrays `Array.from(new Uint8Array(xhr.response))` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

For Chromium Extensions manifest v3, URL.createObjectURL() approach doesn't work anymore because it is prohibited in the service workers.

The best (easiest) way to pass data from a service worker to a content script (and vice-versa), is to convert the blob into a base64 representation.

```
const fetchBlob = async url => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const base64 = await convertBlobToBase64(blob);
    return base64;
};

const convertBlobToBase64 = blob => new Promise(resolve => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        resolve(base64data);
    };
});
```

Then send the base64 to the content script.

Service worker:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id, { type: "LOADED_FILE", base64: base64 });
```

Content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (request, sender) => {
    if (request.type == "LOADED_FILE" && sender.id == '<your_extension_id>') {
        // do anything you want with the data from the service worker.
        // e.g. convert it back to a blob
        const response = await fetch(request.base64);
        const blob = await response.blob();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can confirm, any other seemingly sensible approach is a dead end. Until we get an easy way to pass files to the background script, serializing it ourselves seems to be the way to go.