# How do i access raw data response from a form post in a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, http-post, form-submit

I am trying to build a firefox addon where the user fills out a form and submits it to a server.  I would like to know how to access the response back from the server.  In this example the response is *["SUCCESS", "createAccount"]*

I see the data in this little popup that appears after I click submit, in the Raw Data tab.  (see picture). 
[image]

I just don't know how to access that from my code. This seems like it should be simple but I cannot figure it out.

I have tried overriding the onsubmit and onclick methods/listeners to route them through an ajax/XMLHttpRequest, but I get a content security error (*Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src”). Source: onclick attribute on BUTTON element.)*

I have looked at other SO posts, none of them are specifically for responses from forms in an addon.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not formilliar with Addon development, but what you're looking at is called "response headers". To do something with them, you're probably looking for the [webRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/WebRequest) and more specificly the [onHeadersReceived](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived) method. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but perhaps this will point you into the right direction.

Comment: [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)

Comment: @icecub that did help.  It led me to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/StreamFilter
which unfortunately only works for firefox, I need it to work for chrome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use [webRequests.filterResponseData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData).

The code goes something like this:

```
    var rawdata;
    var listener = function(result){
      let filter = chrome.webRequest.filterResponseData(result.requestId);  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/filterResponseData
      filter.ondata = event => {
      self.data = {
          data: Array.apply(null, new Uint8Array(event.data)),
        
          contentType: result.type
      };
      rawdata = arrayBufferToData.toJSON(event.data);  

      }
       filter.onstop = event => {
       filter.disconnect();
      }

    }
  browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(listener, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},["blocking"]);
```

rawdata will then have the correct values.
Thanks to icecub for pointing the right way.

arrayBufferToData comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365532/is-possible-convert-arraybuffer-to-some-readable-format-like-json-chrome/37601316?noredirect=1#comment89311754_37601316)

Unfortunately this only works for firefox, not chrome.