# How to upload files from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The difficulty comes from the fact that chrome extensions can only make external http requests through the `background.js` file which is separate from the extension and all communication between the two are serialized, which removes files.

I've found some solutions from 1++ years ago, but all seem to be very hacky and not working anymore anyway (as tends to happen to hacky solutions).

So I am left wondering if it is possible at all to upload files from a chrome extension that opens on any website.

Comment: Why do you think you can not make requests form a content script?

Comment: The difficulty @Makyen is passing the files to the content script, where the request can be made

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Please [edit] the question to state *exactly* what you are trying to do. Be specific. For example, "make external http requests" should tell us *exactly* which methods you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: how to pass ArrayBuffer or Blob from content script to the background without losing its type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593896/chrome-extension-how-to-pass-arraybuffer-or-blob-from-content-script-to-the-bac)

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves, I am fairly sure I am making external web requests from a content script in a Chrome extension.

However, if we just consider how to get a file into the background thread, the following options jump to mind, depending on your needs.

1. [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) can be used to access local storage
2. [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) can be used to access the host file system
3. File content could be suitably encoded (say base64) and sent across with [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) in the JSON message.  (I am not sure if there is a message size constraint.  I suppose it could be sent in pieces if there were.)