# How can I save and retrieve associated array from chrome local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension

How can I store associated array in chrome local storage, and retrieve that in the same format? I want to save "identityKeyPair", which is in the form

> identityKeyPair -> { pubKey: ArrayBuffer, privKey: ArrayBuffer }

I tried the below things. But not working out. I am getting [Object Object] on trying to retrieve it.

Saving to local storage

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'identityKeyPair': JSON.stringify(identityKeyPair)}, function() {
          alert('identityKeyPair saved');
        });
```

Trying to retrieve

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(["identityKeyPair"], function(items){
  if (items.identityKeyPair) {
alert(JSON.parse(items.identityKeyPair).pubKey);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saving and retrieving from chrome.storage.sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531102/saving-and-retrieving-from-chrome-storage-sync)

Comment: I suspect this may have something to do with you stringify-ing ArrayBuffers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593896/chrome-extension-how-to-pass-arraybuffer-or-blob-from-content-script-to-the-bac

Answer (score -1):

Please follow these steps while you are using `chrome.storage.sync`

1. Declare storage permissions in your manifest.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Storage",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons":{
"256":"img/icon.png"
    },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "options.html"
    }

  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/app/background.js"]
  }

}
```

2. Reload your App in `chrome://extensions` so that your manifest.json gets updated in your browser.
3. Follow the exact syntax of `chrome.storage.sync` with its callback function.

Sample.js

```
$(".thing").click(function() {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({"myKey": "testPrefs"},function(){
       alert("object stored");
})
    chrome.storage.sync.get("myKey",function(obj){
        alert(obj.myKey);
    })
});
```

This will work for you. I tested this code in my chrome app.

Comment: I am getting empty arrays, `{"pubKey":{},"privKey":{}}`. Have you tried to save the data in `identityKeyPair -> { pubKey: ArrayBuffer, privKey: ArrayBuffer }` format ?