# How to handle APIs in chrome extension MV3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that reads on-screen QR codes, i'm working with manifest 3.0 version and I'm really lost in how to pass messages between contentscript and background scripts, I have my getQR function that gets the screenshot and get all the info, but if I used the code in the contentScript I doesn't let me because the contentscript doesn't have access to tabs API, and if I use it in the backgroundScript it doesn't work because background doesn't have access to DOM, so I'm very confused on how make this work, I'll share the code of getQR function:

**GetQr function**

```
function getQr(tab, left, top, width, height) {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(tab.windowId, { format: "png" }, (dataurl) => {
    const qr = new Image();
    qr.src = dataurl;
    qr.onload = () => {
      const captureCanvasQr = document.createElement("canvas");
      captureCanvasQr.width = width;
      captureCanvasQr.height = height;
      const ctx = captureCanvasQr.getContext("2d");

      ctx.drawImage(qr, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

      const url = captureCanvasQr.toDataURL();
      const qrReader = new QRCode();
      qrReader.callback = (error) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        return qrReader.decode(url);
      };
    };

  });
}
```

I also tried offscreen API solution but also doesn't have access to tabs API :|

Tried with contentScript, with the background script and with the offscreen, none worked

Comment: In order to call chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab, the extension must have either the <all_urls> permission or the activeTab permission.

Comment: Use `fetch` to make a blob out of dataurl + `createImageBitmap` + `OffscreenCanvas` in the background script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service worker(background script) and content script have different context, so we have to use messaging by `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

1. send capture request message. (content -> service_worker)
2. on message, capture tabs by `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` (service_worker)
3. crop or do some operation with `OffscreenCanvas`. (service_worker)
4. encode result blob by `base64`. you can't use `URL.createObjectUrl()` in service worker context. (service_worker).
5. send response message with `base64` (service_worker -> content)

Here's sample of simple screenshot & crop function.

**content.js**

```js
const crop = {
  sx: 200,
  sy: 200,
  ex: 500,
  ey: 500,
  devicePixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio,
};

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  {
    eventType: "request-capture",
    cropPos: { ...crop },
  },
  (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    fetch(response.base64)
      .then((base64) => base64.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        console.log(blob);

        // img crop visual test
        const img = new Image();
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        img.src = url;
        document.querySelector("body")?.appendChild(img);
      });
  }
);
```

**service_worker.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // message from content.js as an capture request
  if (message.eventType === "request-capture") {
    capture(message.cropPos, (croppedBlob) => {
      // serialize blob data to base 64
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(croppedBlob);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64 = reader.result;

        // send test image data to content.js
        sendResponse({
          base64: base64,
        });
      };
    });
    // if you use asynchronous response like this, we should return 'true' for not to close messaging port by chrome.
    return true;
  }
});

function capture(crop, callback) {
  const ratio = crop.devicePixelRatio;
  const sx = Math.min(crop.sx, crop.ex) * ratio;
  const sy = Math.min(crop.sy, crop.ey) * ratio;
  const ex = Math.max(crop.sx, crop.ex) * ratio;
  const ey = Math.max(crop.sy, crop.ey) * ratio;
  const w = ex - sx;
  const h = ey - sy;

  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab({ format: "png" }, (dataUrl) => {
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(w / ratio, h / ratio);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    fetch(dataUrl)
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then((blob) => createImageBitmap(blob))
      .then((img) =>
        ctx?.drawImage(img, sx, sy, w, h, 0, 0, w / ratio, h / ratio)
      )
      .then(() => canvas.convertToBlob())
      .then((blob) => callback(blob));
  });
}
```

see also :

- how to serialize blob by base64 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74522060/20661766

Comment: Thank you sir, implement it differently but get tha main idea with you explananation, thank you a lot.