# How to I refer to the `postMessage()` function from my XHR callbacks?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker, xmlhttprequest-level2

#### The file uploads work perfectly, I can't get the `progess` and `load` events to callback

I have the following in a JavaScript file as my WebWorker code:

#### UploadFileWorker.js

```
function uploadFile(url, m) {
    var f = m.file;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', f, f.name);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
        m.set('status', (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 );
        postMessage(m); // <-- never makes the call, doesn't throw and error either
    });
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        m.set('status',100);
        postMessage(m); // <-- never makes the call, doesn't throw and error either
    });
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.send(fd);
}

function getUploadURL(m) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var url = this.responseText;
        uploadFile(url,m);
    });
    xhr.open('GET', '/upload', false);
    xhr.send();
}

var q = [];

onmessage = function(e) {
    postMessage(e.data);
    q.push(e.data);
    while (q.length > 0) {
        var m = q.pop();
        getUploadURL(m);
    }
};
```

The `postMessage(e.data);` in the `onmessage` function work perfectly.

The `postMessage(m);` in the `xhr.upload.addEventListeners()` callbacks never happen. They worked fine before I tried and move these functions into `WebWorker` code.

**Is this a scope issue?** *If so, how do I prefix the calls to get them to work.?*

For completeness here is how I am defining my instance of `Worker` and kicking it off.

```
onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    var ugv = this.getUploadGridView();
    var fs = this.getFileUploadStore();
    var worker = new Worker('/js/UploadFileWorker.js');
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    };

    var selected = ugv.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

    Ext.each(selected, function(m) {
        var o = {};
        o.name = m.get('name');
        o.size = m.get('size');
        o.status = m.get('status');
        o.file = m.file;
        worker.postMessage(o);
    });
},
```

#### Again the actual uploading of the files works great, I can't figure out how to call `postMessage();` from inside the `xhr` callbacks.

Comment: Where did you define `m` in your Web Worker? Add `worker.onerror = function(message) {console.error(message);};` to see errors. And I believe that the `FormData` object is not defined in Web Workers, unless you use a polyfill (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13970107).

Comment: Like I said the uploads work fine, I am using the polyfill. It is the `postMessage()` callback that I can't get to work. I get no errors either, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is apparently a bug that has been fixed just recently.

Issue [71433002](https://codereview.chromium.org/71433002): Enable XHR upload progress events for Workers. (Closed)

#### Workaround until Chrome gets updated

```
xhr.addEventListener(
```

instead of

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener(
```

This has the drawback that `progress` only gets called for every `1MB`, files smaller than `1MB` never get a `progress` event fired.