# Sending a file from webpage to chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send a file from my webpage to my chrome extension but I don't have a clue how to do it. Could somebody help me please?

Cheers!
Imox

Answer (score 0):

You can send the file's URI to your server. Then your server-side code will download it from the page into the server and process it.

Then proceed to the following steps:

1. Add file path to the `web_accessible_resources` property in the `manifest.json` file
2. Get the URL of the file using `chrome.runtime.getURL('path/to/file')`.
3. Make a **GET** request to the URL:

   ```
   const url = chrome.runtime.getURL('path/to/file');

   fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json()) //assuming file contains json
        .then((json) => doSomething(json));
   ```

Related SO post:

- [Upload a File in a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093722/upload-a-file-in-a-google-chrome-extension)

Related Blog Post:

- [Reading files in a Chrome Extension](https://dev.to/aussieguy0/reading-files-in-a-chrome-extension--2c03)

Chrome Extension Documentation:

- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging)